# Shopping Cart showing delivery

Tags: shopping-cart

Once again apologies as this question has most definitely been asked before.

I have magento 1.9 2.1 If you are logged in as a guest and add an item to your shopping cart the shipping charge does not show up. where if you are logged in it appears.

my shipping is basic as i do not offer multiple shipping options, just spend under a certain amount and pay £* shipping or spend over a certain amount and get FREE shipping.

I was wondering if there is a way that allows any customer to see the shipping charge in there shopping cart before going through the checkout process.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/36028/show-shipping-costs-on-product-page-while-using-table-rates